# "List View Actions in Lightning Experience" action is not available for standard Prdouct2 object like its available for Case, lead etc. object

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud

**List View Actions in Lightning Experience** action is not available for standard Prdouct2 object like its available for Case, lead etc. objects.

screenshot for case object

[image]

Is there any setting which I missed?  or any alternative way?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi,  Problem statement is that I was unable to add any action button on the Product listview in lightning.